# How do I run the code from the completion Handler before initializing a cell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Below is the code of my ViewController

```
class NewsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let networkManager = NetworkManager()
    var newsArray = [NewsModel]()
    var totalResult:Int = 0
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        networkManager.fetchNewsData(forCoutry: "us", category: "business") {  newsDataModel in
            
            self.totalResult = newsDataModel.totalResults
            
            for article in newsDataModel.articles {
                let news = NewsModel(newsTitle: article.title,
                                     urlToNewsWebSite: article.url,
                                     authorWebSiteName: article.source.name,
                                     urlToImage: article.urlToImage ?? "" )
                
                self.newsArray.append(news)
            }
        }

        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
}

extension NewsViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    
}

extension NewsViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "item", for: indexPath) as! NewsCell
        cell.configureCell()
        cell.initData(news: newsArray[indexPath.item])
        collectionView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }
}
```

I need to request data from the network, and then process them in a loop in the completion Handler, and fill the `newsArray = [NewsModel]()`, and only then initialise the cell

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "item", for: indexPath) as! NewsCell
cell.configureCell()
cell.initData(news: newsArray[indexPath.item])
collectionView.reloadData()
return cell
```

But first, the cell is initialised for me, and only then the code from the completion Handler starts working, I figured it out using the breakpoint.

How can I fix this?

Comment: remove the collection view `reloadData` call from inside your cell

Comment: Yes, I added when I was trying to find a solution on my own, trying to come up with something, and forgot to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return the length of the `newsArray` here:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return newsArray.count
}
```

This will cause `cellForItemAt` to not be called if `newsArray` is empty (such as when it is initially).

Next, you should move the `reloadData` call to inside the completion handler, so that `cellForItemAt` is called *after* `newsArray` has items.

```
networkManager.fetchNewsData(forCoutry: "us", category: "business") { [weak self] newsDataModel in
    self?.totalResult = newsDataModel.totalResults
    
    for article in newsDataModel.articles {
        let news = NewsModel(newsTitle: article.title,
                             urlToNewsWebSite: article.url,
                             authorWebSiteName: article.source.name,
                             urlToImage: article.urlToImage ?? "" )
        
        self?.newsArray.append(news)
    }

    // notice this:
    self?.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: That helped! But the application requires me to run self?.newsArray.append(news) in main queue. Can i make DispatchQueue.main.async { self?.newsArray.append(news) }. When I did this, everything worked for me, but the simulator freezes very much when I try to scroll down the cells (there are 30 of them). Is this due to the fact that I am using the simulator? Or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: @Resly34 I just saw that you are also doing `collectionView.reloadData` in `cellForRowAt`. You should not do that.

Comment: Yes, I added when I was trying to find a solution on my own, trying to come up with something, and forgot to remove.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the collectionView.reload data in the completionHandler (dispatch in main queue).
Also, do not reload collectionView in cellForRow, because it may end up with endless loop.

Comment: Yes, I added when I was trying to find a solution on my own, trying to come up with something, and forgot to remove